# C++ Vectors not performing as intuitively as I thought

Tags: c++, vector

I've been trying to learn how to use vectors in c++, and they seem much more complicated in java. In order to add items to a vector, I've had to use an iterator. What I'd like to be able to do is just use add remove functions and loop over them as in java. Is this possible? I'm trying to achieve something like the line I marked with an error below : insert(index 3, number 13), but this throws an error. Thanks in advance.

```
  vector<int> myvector(0,0);
  vector<int>::iterator it;
  it = myvector.begin();
  int q = 0;
  for(it=myvector.begin();q<16;q++){
      it = myvector.insert (it, q);
  }   

 myvector.insert(3,13); //ERROR
```

Comment: `vector.emplace_back(T&& parameter)` or `vector.push_back(..)` does exactly what you want.. See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got advice above how to populate the vector.

If you want to **insert** something at specific index, you can do the following

```
//similar to myvector.insert(3,13); //ERROR
myvector.insert( myvector.begin()+3, 13);
```

The code above will insert 13 before element #3 so that 13 becomes element #3 (numeration starts with 0, so "begin" corresponds to element #0).

To **replace** element #3 with 13, you simply use

```
myvector[3] = 13;
```

Comment: thanks this is exactly the answer I wanted. Didn't know you could use that array-notation for vectors in java

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) is the link where you can learn about the C++ STL(Standard Template Library), such as: vector, queue, stack, list etc.